# How to get a list of unused/available primary keys (primary key ranges from 1 to 999) in an Oracle SQL table?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have employee table where primary key empl_no ranges from 1 to 999. Now I want to know what primary_key are still available for adding new employee(s). For example, below query returns the value 993. That means there are still 6 empl_no availavle which have not been used yet. How can I get the list of those 6 available empl_no using Oracle SQL? Thanks in advance for you help :)

```
SELECT count(empl_no)
FROM emplpyee
WHERE empl_no BETWEEN 1 AND 999;
```

Comment: What you mean by **primary_key are still available** ? , Also do you know what `COUNT` do ? Please check [This](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions032.htm)

Comment: the point of a primary key is to never be reused if there are 6 missing it means that 6 records were probably deleted at some point in time.  Anyway, if you really want to do it generating a tally table with 999 numbers and then doing a left anti join would be one of the fastest/easiest ways or you could look up gaps and islands but the tally is 10 times easier.

Comment: Hi Sami. Thanks for your response. I guess I know the usage of COUNT. Here using COUNT, I just wanted to get how much numbers between 1 to 999 have already been used. In this particular case, result from above query is 993. That means 999-993 = 6 numbers between 1 to 999 are still available for empl_no. Please ignore 'primary key' issue here if thats confusing.

Comment: This problem is a symptom of poor design.

Comment: @jarlh: I disagree. Given that empl_no is the table's natural key and that for some reason they limit employee numbers to be in the range of 0 to 999, they may have to re-use employee numbers at some time.

Comment: "limit employee numbers to be in the range of 0 to 999" isn't a very good choice. Been there, done that (thanks to previous decisions by others.)

Comment: @jarlh: Well, employee numbers in my company are limited to six digits and they had to re-use numbers after several years. I see no fault in this. And I don't think that ever caused any problems either.

Answer (score 3):

```
WITH cteNumbers AS (
    SELECT LEVEL AS NUM
    FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 999
)

SELECT n.NUM
FROM
    cteNumbers n
    LEFT JOIN emplpyee e
    ON n.Num = e.empl_no 
WHERE
    e.empl_no IS NULL
```

Again don't re-use primary keys!  But if you really want to know what is missing use a *numbers* table.  In ORACLE they make it easy using `CONNECT BY`.  Then `LEFT JOIN` back to your table and look for when the `empl_no` is missing.

here is a link that shows oracle's ability to create a numbers table on the fly:
http://rextester.com/CZDKC69208

Comment: Hint for the unexperienced reader: This is an anti-join query. It's just another way of simply writing `WITH cteNumbers AS (...) SELECT num FROM cteNumbers WHERE num NOT IN (SELECT empl_no FROM employee)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
select level from dual connect by level <= 999
minus
select empl_no from emplpyee
```

Comment: It worked and the script is easy to understand for the newbies like me :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Subtract all IDs found in the table from all available IDs. You create all available IDs by determining the number range first (`number(3)` i.e. 0 to 999 in your case) and then recursively create all numbers in that range.

In standard SQL (and in Oracle as of version 11.2) you'd use a recursive CTE for this.

```
with all_ids(id) as
(
  select power(10, data_precision) - 1 as id from all_tab_cols 
    where owner = 'HR' and table_name = 'EMPLOYEES' and column_name = 'EMPLOYEE_ID'
  union all
  select id - 1 from all_ids where id > 0
)
select id from all_ids
minus
select employee_id from employees;
```

Comment: It seems like an overkill, but let say for a minute that this is required. **(1)**   empl_no is most likely of an integer type which has NULL data_precision. **(2)** If the data precision is 12, are we going to generate 1,000,000,000,000 rows?

Comment: @Dudu Markovitz: I just wanted to show how to get the range dynamically. And my company actually even had once a program in production doing exactly this: finding available codes for lookup tables where codes could be re-used. And after years it really happened that some code ranges were extended from `number(2)` to `number(3)` and the programm worked just fine with these database changes. And yes, if the precision were 12, there would probably be many, many IDs available :-)

Comment: I can relate to the use-case you have just described but it is too far from the OP use-case (even the table name is changed...). For those kind of answers I usually add a small demo with a working code that can be reproduced by others. P.s. Returning the gaps + the max value in used will be more effective than generating 1G values.

Answer (score -2):

I am assuming that your table consists some columns X,Column Y other than empl_no.So to find an available primary key you need to find the  of rows which are NULL for column X and Y (that means they are empty).Below query might help..

**SELECT empl_no FROM emplpyee WHERE columnX IS NULL and columnY IS NULL**

Comment: If empl_no 567 isn't in the record set how would your select statement show the OP that 567 is available?  The OP wants the 6 actual numeric empl_no numbers that are not represented in his table